# Can we use Response.Redirect to redirect to the page of other application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on two asp.net webprojects in 3.5framework.

I have used Response.Redirect to redirect to other page with passing data using query string its working fine with in same application but when I am redirecting to other application it is giving me an error.
code:

(working code for same project)

```
Response.Redirect("confirm_book.aspx?Data=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtfname.Text) + "&Data1=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtlname.Text));
```

(not working code when redirecting to other website instead)

```
Response.Redirect("http://abc.com/confirm_book.aspx?Data=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtfname.Text) + "&Data1=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtlname.Text));
```

(on confirm_book.aspx page load event)

```
string fname=Request.QueryString["Data"];
string lname=Request.QueryString["Data1"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you could redirect to another application. You need to specify the absolute address:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/foo.aspx?Data=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtfname.Text));
```

Comment: I am getting this error:   Server Error in '/' Application.

String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Inside your application or inside the application you are redirecting to?

Comment: Well then I guess you will have to fix the code in this application.

Comment: You just said that it is throwing an exception. I wouldn't exactly qualify that state as *working fine* but you know better.

Answer (score 0):

could you put the code of the `Page_Load` of the application you are redirect to ?

i think you are trying to get a QueryString from the URL that it doesn't exist or NULL value.
you may want to check first if the value of the QueryString not NULL

```
if (Request.QueryString["Data"] != null){

string fname=Request.QueryString["Data"];
// do your logic here !
} else {
// the value is NULL , do error logic here
}
```

and make this with every QueryString .